# Base64 encode file in map function

Tags: reactjs, encoding

I need to create my own file array to send to a REST. I send some files true a form and need to base64 encode the file value in the array.

What is the best way to do the in React. I need the content file part to be base64 encoded. Right now i just get the following in my consol.log.

0: "content: '[object File]', fileName: 'download.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg', length: '16344'"

1: "content: '[object File]', fileName: 'download2.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg', length: '8903'"

I need the [object File] to be base64 encoded.

```
var files = Array.from(values.file);
const filesToUpload = files.map((file) =>
"content: '" + file + "', fileName: '" + file.name + "', contentType: '" + file.type + "', length: '" + file.size + "'");
console.log(filesToUpload);
```

Comment: Do you want to convert base64Image to file or reverse?

Comment: I want to convert the [object File] to a base46 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FileReader` to read a file and output Base64-encoded data. You will have to wrap the call in a `Promise` and then use that to map the array.

I've prepared a quick example for you. Note that when you map a `File` to a function returning a `Promise`, you will have to await all the `Promise`s before continuing.

```js
const input = document.querySelector ("#files");

function getBase64 (file) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader ();
    reader.readAsDataURL (file);
    reader.onload = _ => resolve (reader.result);
    reader.onerror = e => reject (e);
  });
}

input.onchange = () => {
  let files = Array.from (input.files);
  files = files.map (async file => ({
    content: await getBase64 (file),
    fileName: file.name,
    contentType: file.type,
    length: file.size
  }));
  Promise.all (files).then (result => console.log (result));
}
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: How do I mix this with the code I got so I get somewhing like.

`0: "content: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUUExMWFhUXGSAaGBgYGB8fHxs', fileName: 'download.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg', length: '16344'"`

Comment: Simply map to a full object. I have updated my answer.

Comment: How do I then turn my result into a var I can use?

Comment: You can use it. I print it using `console.log`, but you can do anything you want.

Comment: I just can't to `var test = result`. Not that easy when it's async. I need to use the array data to post to my REST API togehter with some other for data.

Comment: Then do that, but do it in the callback. Or use another Promise and wrap the whole thing in a function, which you then can `await`.

Comment: If I want to remove some of the base46 incoded string, whre is the best place to dig that? Like .replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

Comment: I need to remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from my base64 encoding.

Comment: Yes, but what is not working with your regex approach?

Comment: Should I put it in the getBase64 function or how should i do it?

Comment: I guess that would be the best way. Alternatively you can iterate over the result set and modify every item.

Comment: Why is this returning nothing?

`function getBase64 (file) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader ();
    reader.readAsDataURL (file);
    let base64String = reader.result.split(',').pop();
    //reader.onload = _ => resolve (reader.result);
    reader.onload = _ => resolve (base64String);
    reader.onerror = e => reject (e);
  });
}`

Comment: Because you are neither using the onload event nor the resolve function anymore. Please read about Promises and Events in JavaScript.